# Need help merging 2 position arrays and for-loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Im making a game and i have 2 arrays, one for bullet variables, and another for enemy  variables. They both have separate for loops that make the objects function, move, follow, aim, etc. Im only worried about the x and y values for now, which are stores in the first 2 array values(so one could be enemies[0][0] is x value).

Is there anyway i can merge the 2 so they interact?

```
for(var i = 0; i<enemies.length;i++){
    enemies[i][0]+=blah blah blah;
    enemies[i][1]+=blah blah blah;
}

for(var i = 0; i<bullets.length;i++){
    bullets[i][0]+=blah blah blah;
    bullets[i][1]+=blah blah blah;
}
```

Based on comments here is my game

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqjlO.jpg

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what do you mean by make the 2 so they interact.?   I would also say for readability and debugging, I would use Object literals.  eg.  bullets[i] = { x: 10, y: 20 ).. etc.

Comment: @Keith - Well for now they cant collide, but thats what i need them to do. So if somehow i can get both of the arrays into a for-loop so they can interact with maybe a hitbox and make the bot dissapear.

Comment: Ok, you need to look into hit-detection.  Unfortunately that is no small feat, as there are lots of ways of doing this.   We really need to know more about your game here I think to be able to help.

Comment: Is is possible to post imgur gifs here? Sorry im new to stack overflow

Comment: @Keith - also i do know how to do hitbox detection, just not with arrays of values

Comment: then transfer arrays to objects

Comment: In that case I think @MarekJanoud solution looks like what your after.

Comment: @Keith - Ok but just in case ill put a video of my game so far if that shows you what i need

Comment: @Keith - just added the video to my post

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0; i < Math.max(enemies.length, bullets.length);i++){
    if(i < enemies.length){
        enemies[i][0]+=blah blah blah;
        enemies[i][1]+=blah blah blah;
    }
    if(i < bullets.length){
        bullets[i][0]+=blah blah blah;
        bullets[i][1]+=blah blah blah;
    }
}
```

based on comment another way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
    //for each bullet
    bullets[i][0]+=blah blah blah;
    bullets[i][1]+=blah blah blah;

    for(var j = 0; j < enemies.length;j++){
        // each enemy
        enemies[j][0]+=blah blah blah;
        enemies[j][1]+=blah blah blah;

        if(enemies[j].BBox.checkCollision(bullets[i])){
            // they collide
        }
    }
}
```

if you have just x and y coordinates its hard to check collision you need bounding box around maybe even for bullet, and i suggest you to use OOP

if you have at least offset, collision check could be done like this:

```
var bbox = {
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0,
    'width': 100,
    'height': 200
};

bbox.checkCollision = function(bullet){
    return (bullet[0] > bbox.x && bullet[0] < bbox.x + bbox.width
        && bullet[1] > bbox.y && bullet[1] < bbox.y + bbox.height);
}

for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < enemies.length;j++){
        bbox.x = enemies[j][0];
        bbox.y = enemies[j][1];

        if(bbox.checkCollision(bullets[i])){
            // bullets[i] collide with enemies[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seen as this a game, and performance usually matters.  It might be worth pointing out this would be slower..

Comment: whats with the BBox part? i just googled it and its about a box collison

I think i can make my own but thanks :)

Comment: bbox = bounding box

Comment: Yeah i do that, but your way seems intriguing to me, ill try it out

(also here is the vid http://imgur.com/B2vQGOQ)